# I need to process texts having tweets. Either using regular expression or even the normal python code

Tags: python, regex

Text contains tokenised wrods, Only exact matches are required for the tweet text. Thus `“#eat”` or `“@eat”` or `“eating”` or `“eat23”` or `“eat-Python”` etc are not an exact match and can be ignored. If a word ends in one of the following forms of punctuation: ! , ? . ’ ” then it can be regarded as an exact match, e.g. “Python is a course you should not eat!” would match on “eat”. The words should be treated as case

I am tokenising the text using following function:

```
def sentenceBreak(text):
    '''This function is used to tokenize the text/sentence and store it in the form of bag of words.
    Parameters:
    text: The text/sentence to be tokenised and stored as bag of words
    Return:
    bag_of_words: Dictionary with key as tokenized word and value as frequency of the word in text/sentence
    #input example: text = "hello yes HEllo yES yes"
    #output example: {"hello": 2, "yes": 3}
    '''
    bag_of_words = {}
    t = text.lower().split() # Storing words with case insensitivity     
    #Question mark: if a word looks like 'live!!!' should 'live' be counted?
    for index, word in enumerate(t):
        if word[-1] in string.punctuation:
            bag_of_words[word[:-1]] = bag_of_words.get(word[:-1], 0) + 1
        else:
            bag_of_words[word] = bag_of_words.get(word, 0) + 1
            
    return bag_of_words
```

Comment: You might want to start and end a code snippet with triple back ticks ```.  https://fleep.zendesk.com/hc/article_attachments/360000819293/triple_backticks.gif

Answer (score 0):

You can write more readable code with `collections.Counter`:

```py
import string
from collections import Counter


def sentenceBreak(text):
    words = (x.strip(string.punctuation) for x in text.lower().split())
    return Counter(words)


counts = sentenceBreak("hello, yes HEllo!! yES yes?!")
print(counts)
print(counts["yes"])
print(counts["hello"])
print([(word, count) for word, count in counts.items()])
```

Will outputs:

```
Counter({'yes': 3, 'hello': 2})
3
2
[('hello', 2), ('yes', 3)]
```